# Why doesn´t the browser show the mistake? There's nothing in the <p>-tag?

Tags: javascript, dom, getelementsbytagname

```
    function createRow() {
                  var table = document.getElementById("manipulation");
                  var x = table.insertRow(0);
                  var e = table.rows.length-1;
                  var l = table.rows[e].cells.length;
                  for( var c = 0; c< l; c++){
                    table.rows[0].insertCell(c);
                    table.rows[0].cells[c].innerHTML = "&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                  }
                  function out1(createRow){
                  document.getElementsByTagName('printVal')[0].replaceChild(document.createTextNode("Zeilen: " + (table.children.length).toString()).document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].firstChild);
                  document.getElementsByTagName('Spalten')[1].replaceChild(document.createTextNode("Spalten: " + (table.children.length).toString()).document.getElementsByTagName('Spalten')[0].firstChild);
               }
             }

 ...
<button type="button" name="z.hinzufügen" onclick="createRow()" >Zeile hinzufügen</button>

<p id= "Spalten"></p>
```

The code has to show the number of cells and rows. The challenge is to replace document.write() with DOM-Methods, without using document.write(). But how I wrote it doesn´t work. What´s the mistake?

Does anybody have a better idea how to replace document.write() with DOM-Methods?

I am very thankful for any help or ideas.

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` is looking for... well... the tag name! For example `getElementsByTagName('input')` would get all `<input>` elements. You probably want `getElementById()` instead.

Comment: Now, I changed getElementsByTagName() to getElementById(). But still it doesn´t work...